# Edit library source file in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing code for a library consumed by another program that get compiled and deployed. I have followed [these steps](https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/) to edit my javascript directly in the browser but my changes are never applied. 
Can you not edit a javascript file part of a library in place?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the file. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52451514/1669860) for this other question. Remember to press Command+S or Control+S to commit your changes.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing this unsuccessfully but found the solution. I needed to set a flag to false in my code base to use uncompiled javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong. I needed to set a flag to false in my code base to use uncompiled javascript.