# AngularJS - Edit Scope Function from Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am doing some testing on a product and I am attempting to edit one of my controller's scope functions (from Chrome Dev Tools) and then call this newly edited function either via the already-existing button that's set up to call it or via console. I'm having trouble with this though because my changes are not being picked up. I have been scouring SO for a couple hours but haven't been able to find a working answer yet. Is there a trick to refreshing a specific function (or possibly the controller itself) without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the code from the Sources panel.

[image: the file to edit]

Add your new code...

[image: the new code]

**And then press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (all other OSs) to save**. When there's an asterisk next to the file name, it means that your new code hasn't been applied.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. The vm that gets generated with the original source code wouldn't update - even after I called $digest. I did discover that I did not need to edit my scope function however because I was able to access a dependency from the console (which was my goal of the "newly edited function"). I appreciate your help in this though! :-)